# langchain MultiPromptChain to call`predict_and_parse` in destination chains in order to return structured parsed output

Tags: python, langchain

I have a MultiPromptChain with a few destination chains. I am trying to return a dictionary as response rather than a string. I have successfully created multiple LLMChains as follows:

```
output_parser = StructuredOutputParser.from_response_schemas(response_schemas)


prompt = ChatPromptTemplate(
    messages=[HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(prompt_template)],
    input_variables=["input"],
    partial_variables={"format_instructions": output_parser.get_format_instructions()},
    output_parser=output_parser
)

llm = VertexAI(
    model_name='text-bison@001',
    temperature=0.0,
    verbose=True)

chain1 = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt, verbose=True)
```

on this chain, if i run the following command:

```
chain1.predict_and_parse(input="who were the Normans?")
```

I successfully get my response as a dictionary. However I am struggling to get this response as dictionary if i combine multiple chains into a `MultiPromptChain`.

For example:

```
destination_chains = [chain1, chain2, chain3]

default_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template("{input}")
default_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=default_prompt)

router_template = MULTI_PROMPT_ROUTER_TEMPLATE.format(
      destinations=destinations_str
)
router_prompt = PromptTemplate(
      template=router_template,
      input_variables=["input"],
      output_parser=RouterOutputParser(),
)

router_chain = LLMRouterChain.from_llm(llm, router_prompt)

chain = MultiPromptChain(
      router_chain=router_chain,
      destination_chains=destination_chains,
      default_chain=default_chain, verbose=True
  )
```

If I then run my chain with :  `chain.run(input_text)`
My response in this case will be a string with the JSON formatting.
How do I need to modify my code to have the MultiPromptChain to return a dictionary?